# Using the dominated convergence theorem to show the following equality

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

[image]

I am trying to show the above using the Dominated convergence theorem. I have let the integrand be the limit point of a sequence of functions obtained by replacing the log by its expansion ($\log(\frac{1}{x})=\log((\frac{1}{x}-1)+1)$). I have reduced the problem to finding the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}-k}(1-x)^{k-1}}dx$$
but I feel Cike this is the wrong approach. How can this be shown using The Dominated convergence Theorem, and more specifically how can we choose an appropriate sequence of functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = e^{-t} \therefore dx=-e^{-t}dt$. The integral is,
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{te^{-t/3}}{1-e^{-t}}dt$$
$\because 0 < e^{-t} <1$ for $t \in (0,\infty)$, we can express the denominator as a geometric progression.
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-t/3}(1+e^{-t}+\cdots)dt$$
$\because \int_0^{\infty}te^{-at}dt=\frac{1}{a^2}$, we get,
$$I=3^2+\frac{3^2}{4^2}+\frac{3^2}{7^2}\cdots=9\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}$$
which is the desired result. Hope this helps.